# How can I pass additional data to a scheduled job function in node-schedule

Tags: node.js, node-schedule

I have the classic scenario that has already been done before by other systems.

In my use case, users submit a date and an email message to be sent at that date. I'm using the node-schedule library to schedule these email deliveries. Here's the part of my code that handles scheduling:

```
async function scheduleEmail(date, content) {
    const sendDate = new Date(date);
    const job = schedule.scheduleJob(sendDate, async function () {
        // TODO: Send the email here
        console.log('Sending email:', content);
    });
}
```

I'm a bit confused about how the scheduleJob function will know which content to send when the scheduled time is reached. The function only takes a date parameter, so how will it retrieve and pass the corresponding email content back to me for sending?

Can anyone please clarify how this part of the code should work?

Answer (score 0):

You are passing **content** variable to your **job function**.
This variable will be saved even function is stopped.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).